# Weak convergence to a Gaussian measure in coarser topology induced by a covariance operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

I'm currently studying Gaussian measures on Hilbert spaces and would like to find conditions under which convergence to a Gaussian measure with respect to a coarser topology induced by a covariance operator implies weak convergence with respect to the original topology. This question is an asymptotic version of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316202/is-a-gaussian-measure-on-a-hilbert-space-determined-by-the-coarser-topology-indu) related question, where it was shown that if two measures agree on such a coarser topology, then they also agree on the original topology.

Full details are as follows:

Let $H$ be a real separable Hilbert space and $S$ a bijective, non-negative, self-adjoint trace-class operator on $H$ (for example the covariance operator of some Gaussian measure on $H$). Denote the inner product by $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$ and define a new inner product $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle_1$ on $H$ by 
$$
\left\langle x,y  \right\rangle_1 := \left\langle \sqrt{S} x, \sqrt{S} y \right\rangle, \qquad x,y \in H.
$$
This inner product is weaker than $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot  \right\rangle$, as for the induced norms we have that $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_1 \leq \left\lVert T \right\rVert_{op} \left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert$. Let $H_1$ be the completion of $H$ with respect to $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_1$. Then $H_0 \subseteq H_1$ densely and as a Borel set.

Let $\mathcal{B}(H)$ and $\mathcal{B}(H_1)$ denote the Borel sets of $H$ and $H_1$, with respect to the norms $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert$ and $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_1$,respectively. Then $\mathcal{B}(H_1) \cap H \subseteq \mathcal{B}(H)$, where $\mathcal{B}(H_1) \cap H = \{ A \cap H \colon A \in \mathcal{B}(H_1) \}$.

Finally, let $\nu_n$ be a sequence of probability measures on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H))$ with trace class covariance operators and $\mu$ be a Gaussian measure on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H))$. Then $\mu$ is completely determined by its values on $\mathcal{B_1}\cap H$ (see the above linked question).

**My question is:**
If $\nu_n$ converges weakly on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H_1)\cap H)$ to $\mu$ ("weakly" in the probabilistic sense, i.e. with respect to real-valued, bounded continuous functions), does this convergence also hold on $(H,\mathcal{B}(H))$, maybe under some additional conditions on the covariance operator defining the weaker inner product?

Comment: Why the artificial generality? You only need to understand the example $H=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $S$ being the map $(x_n)\mapsto(a_n x_n)$ where the $a_n$ are nonnegative and $\sum a_n<\infty$.

Comment: related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202088/weak-convergence-of-probability-measures-on-weak-versus-strong-dual

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam thanks for the comments, of course one can go to sequences if it helps, but I don't see how. Also, regarding your reference: How does strong convergence play a role here? In case you had some further insight, could you please elaborate?